# On evaluating $\frac{\Delta ^2 x}{\Delta x}$ as $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I am trying to evaluate the value of

$$\frac{\Delta \bigg ( \frac{\Delta x}{a + \Delta x}\bigg)}{\Delta x}$$

as $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$.

After expanding, I arrived at

$$\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \,a \frac{\Delta ^2 x}{\Delta x}\times\frac{1}{(a+\Delta x)^2}.$$

So I basically need to determine

$$\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Delta ^2 x}{\Delta x}.$$

The final answer in the book says the second expression above evaluates to $\frac{1}{a}$. So I inferred from it that

$$\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Delta ^2 x}{\Delta x}=1.$$

I couldn't find this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book's answer appears to be the answer to the limit of $$\frac{\bigg ( \frac{\Delta x}{a + \Delta x}\bigg)}{\Delta x}$$

Comment: Thank you. I am still somehow intrigued about how one would go about evaluating $$\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Delta ^2 x}{\Delta x}.$$ Is it even meaningful?